# PHP count how many times a week certain operation occured

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, date, comparison

I have this array data structure:

```
$records = [];

$records[] = ['id' => 1, 'date' => '2017-03-12', 'operation' => 'sent_email'];
$records[] = ['id' => 1, 'date' => '2017-03-13', 'operation' => 'sent_email'];
$records[] = ['id' => 1, 'date' => '2017-03-13', 'operation' => 'sent_email'];
$records[] = ['id' => 1, 'date' => '2017-03-14', 'operation' => 'forgot_password'];
$records[] = ['id' => 1, 'date' => '2017-03-14', 'operation' => 'sent_email'];
$records[] = ['id' => 2, 'date' => '2017-03-14', 'operation' => 'sent_email'];
$records[] = ['id' => 2, 'date' => '2017-03-14', 'operation' => 'forgot_password'];
$records[] = ['id' => 1, 'date' => '2017-03-27', 'operation' => 'sent_email'];
$records[] = ['id' => 1, 'date' => '2017-03-29', 'operation' => 'sent_email'];
```

In this array I store operations that were done by website visitors. Obviously visitor can be identified by an id number.

What I want to do is to count how many times in a week (between Monday and Sunday inclusively) each visitor used 'sent_email' operation.

For example: first record with 'sent_email' operation shows that this operation happened in '2017-03-12' (Sunday), so that means this operation took place just once in that week for user with an id = 1.

Other next three 'sent_email' operations for user with an id = 1 happened three times in another week. (2017-03-13, 2017-03-13, 2017-03-14 those three dates belong to the same week).

I know that I probably need to loop through each record and somehow to check those dates if they belong to the same week, but I feel confused and stuck here,  I don't understand logical steps needed to accomplish it. I would be really grateful if anyone could give me an explanation or pseudo code, whatever it is that would help me to tackle this problem, I really enjoy solving problems myself but because I'm stuck, I just need someone to get me up and running.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2):

The DateTime object and the strtotime() functions both understand relative date strings, so you can do neat things like "last tuesday" and "3 days ago".

Some pseudo-code to get you started:

```
// figure out when your monday is
monday = ...

// figure out when your sunday is
sunday = ...

// loop over all records
foreach $record:

    // skip records outside the date range you want
    if date < monday or date > sunday then skip this record;

    // skip records not of the type you want
    if operation != email then skip this record;

    // register a hit for this user
    increment counter for user
```